# What does this code do exactly at the hardware level or above?

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi+

I was reading up on the math for drawing a circle and it made sense, but to translate that too C++ was nonsensical. It appears there is some underlying math or computer functions I'm missing when using 
`SetPixel(hdc, x, y , COLOREF bg);` in Win32 API GDI.

However, I managed to find code that did draw a circle but I don't really understand what it does on any level apart from the radius float value 
and `*` operator has something to do with the circle drawing.

Could someone please explain exactly 
what this is doing and how you figured it out?

```
//THIS CODE:
     float radius = 120.0;
                    for(int y =-radius; y<=radius; y++)
                    for(int x =-radius; x<=radius; x++)
                    if(x*x+y*y <= radius*radius)
                    SetPixel(DCWindowHandle, 200+x, 200+y, red);



//SCROLL DOWN HERE TO SEE IT IN USE:

#include <windows.h>
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND , UINT , WPARAM , LPARAM);
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{
    static TCHAR szAppName[] = TEXT ("Marble Engine");
    HWND WindowHandle;
    MSG Message;
    WNDCLASS WindowClass;
    WindowClass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    WindowClass.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    WindowClass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    WindowClass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    WindowClass.hInstance = hInstance;
    WindowClass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    WindowClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    WindowClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) GetStockObject (WHITE_BRUSH);
    WindowClass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    WindowClass.lpszClassName = szAppName;
    if(!RegisterClass (&WindowClass))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("This Program Requires Nothing!"),
        szAppName, MB_ICONERROR);
        return 0;
    }
    WindowHandle = CreateWindow(szAppName,
    TEXT ("The Shit Program!"),
    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
    CW_USEDEFAULT,
    CW_USEDEFAULT,
    CW_USEDEFAULT,
    CW_USEDEFAULT,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    hInstance,
    NULL);
    ShowWindow(WindowHandle, iCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(WindowHandle);
    while(GetMessage(&Message, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&Message);
        DispatchMessage(&Message);
    }
    return Message.wParam;
}
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND WindowHandle, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    HDC DCWindowHandle;
    PAINTSTRUCT PaintStruct;
    RECT rect;
    TCHAR * text = TEXT("Hello there this is test!");
    COLORREF red = RGB(255, 0, 0);
    switch(Message)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
        DCWindowHandle = GetDC(WindowHandle);
        ReleaseDC(WindowHandle, DCWindowHandle);
        return 0;
        case WM_PAINT:
        {
            DCWindowHandle = BeginPaint(WindowHandle, &PaintStruct);
            GetClientRect(WindowHandle, &rect);
            DrawText(DCWindowHandle, TEXT("Bother!"), -1, &rect, DT_SINGLELINE | DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER);


            float radius = 120.0;

            for(int y =-radius; y<=radius; y++)
            for(int x =-radius; x<=radius; x++)
            if(x*x+y*y <= radius*radius)
            SetPixel(DCWindowHandle, 200+x, 200+y, red);

            EndPaint( WindowHandle, &PaintStruct);
            return 0;
        }
        case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(WindowHandle, Message, wParam , lParam);
}
```

Comment: I really don't care what you put in your code for your own pleasure. If you're going to post code here there's no need to include the four-letter expletives.

Answer (score 4):

It's one of the more inefficient ways to draw a circle. What it does is go through, one by one, all the pixels in a square whose sides are the same length as the diameter of the circle. If distance from the pixel to the centre of the square is less than or equal to the radius of the circle then it colours that pixel red.  All other pixels in the square are left unmodified.

Comment: What is the diameter the radius? 

What does x * x+y * y do ?
-radius*-radius + -radius*-radius?

Comment: if you "-120.0  * -120.0 + -120.0 * 120.0"
 
that doesn't make sense.

It's like reversed "120.0 * 120.0 - 120.0 * 120.0"

Comment: The diameter is twice the radius. The radius is 120. The `x*x+y*y <= radius*radius` expression in the code is where it figures out if the distance of the pixel at `x, y` is less than or equal to the radius of the circle. It does this by using the Pythagorean Theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem

Comment: What I need is a real life maths to c++ translation made simple as possible.

any references?

Comment: n0rd : I think C++ does retarded things to get simple stuff done infact Id almost say that the entire binary programming language is way more 
simple in terms of commands then Assembly language in comparison if the computer was built to do the work for you "which it should".

Why are we not talking to computers with english based language text
 instead of abstract garbage baffles the mind.

Comment: @DominicHughes I don't think C++ is the problem here. You seem to have trouble understanding the math, and it's pretty basic "real life" math.

Comment: The C++ equation `x*x+y*y <= r*r` can be read "x times x plus y times y less than or equal to r times r".

Comment: Ross Ridge : I have trouble realizing , observing and using the translation of real life maths too C++ apart from the obvious operators and math functions which don't really describe what they do directly also by reference they only say "calculate the sin of n angle" or something like that ... why are there no pictures or video explaining each function in detail seriously though do I actually have to buy maths books to tell a computer I want a circle drawn why can't there be an automatic function that is fundamentally optimized by 100s of people around the world that we can all use.

Comment: @DominicHughes: There is, on Windows it's called [Ellipse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162510%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). But you didn't say that's what you wanted.

Comment: I need to draw an octagon , I was gunna use a circle as a basis then straighten each right angle of it's circumference.

Comment: Seriously would build my own computer from scratch but don't have the facility to do it and write my own programming language that's like speaking to a person .

Comment: @DominicHughes You might want to put off programming for a while. Once you're older, maybe learned some more math in school, I think you'll be able to appreciate it more. As it stands now I think you're just to continue finding it a very frustrating experience.

Comment: I do not want to appreciate something this broken , complexity does not win over simplicity because with simplicity you get more access potential then with complexity at fast speeds because there are less hurdles in the way.

Comment: Sure, if we could tell computers what we wanted in English that would be great.  The only problem is we have no idea how to do it!  Despite extensive research, making a computer understand natural language is still an unsolved problem.

Comment: If you want to draw an octogon you need to be better at maths. Instead of complaining that the computers are letting you down, you should look in the mirror and recognise that you have plenty still to learn.

Comment: Incidentally, the best way to build an octogon is probably out of a rectangle, two squares, and four triangles.